# how to display image from different folder or same folder with php and SQL but without repeating code?

Tags: php, image

I have 3 page where I want to display different image cateory. I can display them fine from my DB but I need to copy-past the entire code 3 time

One issue that I have is that my images are categories into 3 different folders...(images/flower, images/food, images/gift) but I can avert that by placing all of my images just inside "images" folder and not "images/something folder"

```
require_once("aftercare_service_sys_db.php");

function stmt_query(){

$heidisql = pdo_con();

$query = '
    SELECT * FROM product_items as pi 
    INNER JOIN product_category as pc ON pi.item_category_id = pc.item_category_id
    WHERE pc.item_category_id = **2**
    ORDER BY pi.product_item_id ASC LIMIT 8';

$result = $heidisql->query($query);

return $result;

}

function product_item_details() {

$output = '';

$result = stmt_query();

    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $output .='<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 mb-4">'
                . '<div class="card h-100">';

    $output .= '<a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="images/'.$row["product_item_imgpath"].' " alt=" '.$row["product_item_titlename"].' "></a>';

    $output .= '<div class="card-body">';


    $output .= '<h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">'.$row["product_item_titlename"].'</a></h5>

                        <h5>Price: '.$row["item_price"].'</h5>

                        <p class="card-text">'.$row["product_item_description"].' </p>
                      </div>';

    $output .='<div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</a></small>
                    </div>';

    $output .=' </div>'
            . '</div>';


    } 

    return $output;

    }
```

I place this code inside a php page so that I can include it into multiple pg where I needed.

**the problem is that I need a way to change this** WHERE pc.item_category_id = **2** <- I need to be able to modify that without repeating the entire code on all 3 my pages

E.g pg 1(flower): item_category_id = 1, pg 2(food): item_category_id = 2

**OR that** src="images/'.$row["product_item_imgpath"].'

E.g pg 1(flower): src="images/flower/ , pg 2(food): images/food/

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass as a parameter to stmt_query() function.
Like:

```
function stmt_query($condition){
...
 WHERE pc.item_category_id = {{$condition}}
...
}
```

Comment: Could you be a little bit more clear... are you talking about placing an sql inside another sql (nested sql)? id=1=flower, id=2=food, id=3=gift

Comment: what I mean is: to pass the parameter that you want in the WHERE into the stmt_query function. So, each time you call your stmt_query you can specify your category code